# How do I construct a function/type that observes each transition in this state machine?

Tags: haskell, finite-automata

The gist of my question is that I have a deterministic state automata that is transitioning according to a list of moves, and I want this sequence of transition to serve as a "computational context" for another function. This other function would observe the state machine at each transition, and do some computation with it, vaguely reminiscent of a model-view pattern. Trivially this other function might simply read the current state the machine is in, and print it to screen.

My implementation of the state machine:

```
data FA n s = FA { initSt1 :: n, endSt1 :: [n], trans1 :: n -> s -> n }

-- | Checks if sequence of transitions arrives at terminal nodes
evalFA :: Eq n => FA n s -> [s] -> Bool
evalFA fa@(FA _ sfs _ ) = (`elem` sfs) . (runFA fa)

-- | Outputs final state reached by sequence of transitons
runFA :: FA n s -> [s] -> n
runFA (FA s0 sfs trans) = foldl trans s0
```

And example:

```
type State = String
data Trans = A | B | C | D | E

fa :: FA State Trans
fa = FA ("S1") ["S4","S5"] t1

-- | Note non-matched transitions automatically goes to s0
t1 :: State -> Trans -> State
t1 "S1" E = "S1"
t1 "S1" A = "S2"
t1 "S2" B = "S3"
t1 "S2" C = "S4"
t1 "S3" D = "S5"
t1 _  _   = "S1"

runFA fa [A,B]   -- | S3
```

Comment: Make it produce the list of intermediate states, i.e. use `scanl` instead of `foldl`?

Comment: yeah that makes a lot of sense, but is there an equivalent scanl for foldM, which I would use instead of foldl in the case of non-deterministic FSA

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid. Since a monadic computation can potentially fail, one can't emit anything before the entire list has been consumed to determine that it succeeded. Depending on the details, it could be possible for your special situation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to split this answer in two parts.  The first part will answer your original question and the second part will answer the non-deterministic FSA question you raised in the comments.

## Pipes

You can use `pipes` to interleave effects between computations.  First, I'll begin with the slightly modified version of your code:

```
data FA n s = FA { initSt1 :: n, endSt1 :: [n], trans1 :: n -> s -> n }

data State = S1 | S2 | S3 | S4 | S5 deriving (Eq, Show)
data Trans = A | B | C | D | E deriving (Read)

fa :: FA State Trans
fa = FA (S1) [S4,S5] t1

-- | Note non-matched transitions automatically goes to s0
t1 :: State -> Trans -> State
t1 S1 E = S1
t1 S1 A = S2
t1 S2 B = S3
t1 S2 C = S4
t1 S3 D = S5
t1 _  _ = S1
```

The only difference is that I'm using an enumeration instead of a `String` for the `State`.

Next, I will implement your transitions as a `Pipe`:

```
runFA :: (Monad m, Proxy p) => FA n s -> () -> Pipe (StateP n p) s n m r
runFA (FA _ _ trans) () = forever $ do
    s <- request ()
    n <- get
    put (trans n s)
    respond n
```

Let's look closely at the type of the `Pipe`:

```
() -> Pipe (StateP n p) s n m r
                   ^    ^ ^
                   |    | |
 'n' is the state -+    | |
                        | |
          's's come in -+ +- 'n's go out
```

So you can think of this as an effectful `scanl`.  It receives a stream of `s`s using `request` and outputs a stream of `n`s using `respond`.  It can actually interleave effects directly if we want, but I will instead outsource effects to other processing stages.

When we formulate it as a `Pipe`, we have the luxury of choosing what our input and output streams will be.  For example, we can connect the input to the impure `stdin` and connect the output to the impure `stdout`:

```
import Control.Proxy
import Control.Proxy.Trans.State

main = runProxy $ execStateK (initSt1 fa) $
    stdinS >-> takeWhileD (/= "quit") >-> mapD read >-> runFA fa >-> printD
```

That's a processing pipeline that you can read as saying:

- Execute the following `Pipe` with an initial state of `initSt`
- Stream values from standard intput
- Keep streaming until one of those values is `"quit"`
- Apply `read` to all values to convert them to `Trans`es
- Run them through our scanning finite-state automaton
- Print the `State`s that the automaton emits

Let's try it:

```
>>> main
A
S1
B
S2
C
S3
A
S1
quit
S2
>>>
```

Notice how it also returns out the the final `State` that our automaton was in.  You could then `fmap` your test over this computation to see if it ended in a terminal node:

```
>>> fmap (`elem` [S1, S2]) main
A
S1
B
S2
C
S3
A
S1
quit
True
```

Alternatively, we can connect our automaton to pure inputs and outputs, too:

```
import Control.Proxy.Trans.Writer
import Data.Functor.Identity

main = print $ runIdentity $ runProxy $ runWriterK $ execStateK (initSt1 fa) $
    fromListS [A, C, E, A] >-> runFA fa >-> liftP . toListD
```

That pipeline says:

- Run this within a pure computation (i.e. `runIdentity) and print the pure result
- Use `Writer` to log all the states we have visited
- Use `State` to keep track of our current state
- Feed a list of predefined transitions purely
- Run those transitions through our FSA
- Log the outputs to the `Writer`, using `liftP` to specify that we targeting `Writer`

Let's try this, too:

```
>>> main
(S2,[S1,S2,S4,S1])
```

That outputs the final state and the list of visited states.

## ListT

Now, there was a second question that you raised, which is how do you do effectful non-deterministic computations.  Daniel was actually incorrect: You can interleave effects with non-determinism using `pipes`, too!  The trick is to use `ProduceT`, which is the `pipes` implementation of `ListT`.

First, I will show how to use `ProduceT`:

```
fsa :: (Proxy p) => State -> Trans -> ProduceT p IO State
fsa state trans = do
    lift $ putStrLn $ "At State: " ++ show state
    state' <- eachS $ case (state, trans) of
        (S1, A) -> [S2, S3]
        (S2, B) -> [S4, S5]
        (S3, B) -> [S5, S2]
        (S4, C) -> [S2, S3]
        (S5, C) -> [S3, S4]
        (_ , _) -> [S1]
    return state'
```

The above code says:

- Print the current state
- Bind many possible transitions non-deterministically
- Return the new selected state

To avoid manual state passing, I will wrap `fsa` in `StateT`:

```
import qualified Control.Monad.Trans.State as S

fsa2 :: (Proxy p) => Trans -> S.StateT State (ProduceT p IO) State
fsa2 trans = do
    s <- S.get
    s' <- lift $ fsa s trans
    S.put s'
    return s'
```

Now I can run the generator on multiple transitions easily by using `mapM`.  When I'm done, I compile it to a `Producer` using `runRespondT`:

```
use1 :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p State IO ()
use1 () = runRespondT $ (`S.execStateT` S1) $ do
    mapM_ fsa2 [A, B, C]  -- Run the generator using four transitions
```

This produces a pipe whose effects are to print the states it is traversing and it outputs a stream of final states it encounters.  I'll hook up the output to a printing stage so we can observe both simultaneously:

```
>>> runProxy $ use1 >-> printD
At State: S1
At State: S2
At State: S4
S2
S3
At State: S5
S3
S4
At State: S3
At State: S5
S3
S4
At State: S2
S1
```

We can observe the automaton's path it takes and how it backtracks.  It print outs where it currently is after each step and then emits all 7 of its final states as soon as it arrives at them.

Sorry if this post is a little bit unpolished, but it's the best I can do in a hurry.

Comment: Man I gotta say it's magical how despite how poorly my questions are phrased, you always know exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: :) It's because I used to ask the exact same confusing questions myself.

Comment: I propose a special case on SO where we're allowed to upvote @GabrielGonzalez 's answers more than once!

Comment: Seriously, one day all his answers have to be compiled into a book and be published by O'Reilly